# How to add more fields in my html/php form

Tags: php, html, forms

How to add more fields in my simple form
i mean i wanna add like username,email , subject , subject 2 , subjet 3 .. just more fields in the form and thats all

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Store form data in .txt file</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
 Enter Your Text Here:<br>
 <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 
</form>

</body>
</html>


<?php
           
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];



$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, $data, $data2);
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" name="username">` ... ?? [<input>: The Input (Form Input) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

Comment: How to add it on/in the php code

Comment: $username = $_POST['username'];

Comment: Study a bit more, you will learn faster.

Comment: The PHP manual has a simple tutorial on [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php), I suggest you read that and maybe another forms tutorial first

Answer (score 2):

In the php form or html form, you can use the code below

```
<form method="POST">
<label>Enter Your Text Here:</label>

<!-- New fields form -->
<input type="text" name="username"/>
<input type="text" name="email"/>
<input type="text" name="subject"/>
<input type="text" name="subject2"/>
<input type="text" name="subjet3"/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

Code processed by php in below

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
$subjet3 = $_POST['subjet3'];
```

Comment: I tried but i dont got nothing in data.txt
`<?php
              
if(isset($_POST['textdata']))
{
$data=$_POST['textdata'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
$subjet3 = $_POST['subjet3'];


$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');

fwrite($fp, $data, $data2);
fclose($fp);
}
?>`

Comment: You can rewrite the code below, create a file named index.php, then copy the code below into the index.php file :

Comment: <label>Enter Your Text Here:</label>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
            <tr>
                <td width="30"><span>User Name</span></td>
                <td width="30"><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
            </tr>

Comment: Advanced to put in index.php file

<tr>
                <td width="30"><span>E-mail</span></td>
                <td width="30"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30"><span>Subject</span></td>
                <td width="30"><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="30"><span>Subject2</span></td>
                <td width="30"><input type="text" name="subject2" id="subject2" /></td>
            </tr>

Comment: Advanced to put in index.php file below:

<tr>
                <td width="30"><span>Subjet3</span></td>
                <td width="30"><input type="text" name="subjet3" id="subjet3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td></td>
                <div align="center">
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
                </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
    </form>

Comment: After that, you create an insert.php file to receive the input process sent from the index.php file, and enter the code below:
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
$subjet3 = $_POST['subjet3'];

Advanced to put in insert.php file below:

Comment: echo "$username <br> $email <br> $subject <br> $subject2 <br> $subjet3";
if(!empty($username) || !empty($email) || !empty($subject) || !empty($subject2) || !empty($subjet3)){
$txtData = $username . "," . $email . "," . $subject . "," . $subject2 . "," . $subjet3;
$fp = fopen("data.txt","a"); // $fp is now the file pointer to file $username
    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp,$txtData."\n"); // Write information to the file
        fclose($fp); // Close the file
    } 
}
?>

and you can see the results.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML form

```
<form method="post">
 Enter Your Text Here:<br>
 <input type="text" name="textdata"><br>

 <!-- New fields -->
 <input type="text" name="subject"/>
 <input type="text" name="subject2"/>
  
 <input type="submit" name="submit">
 
</form>
```

In the PHP code

```
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$subject2 = $_POST['subject2'];
```

Additional notes : Taking form data directly like the above is risky. You need to sanitize the input values.

E.g.

```
$subject = addslashes($_POST['subject']);
```